# Is there a function like [SyncVar(hook = "OnChangeHealth")] without NetworkBehaviour?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a function in Unity, that you can use like this:

```
[SyncVar(hook = "OnChangeHealth")]
int health;
```

to run a method everytime a variable changes, just without the need of NetworkBehaviour?

Comment: I would say just do what @Daniel Mathews said below, or even just make your own Getter/Setter and put some things you need to do in there.

Comment: What @Daniel Mathews says will do the trick, but won't act as SyncVar, as SyncVar is marked as a dirty variable, so it's synchronized EVERY frame, in Daniel's solution, it will only sync when it's modified (which is better).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a simple attribute you can use, however - I generally go for something like this -

```
    public class HealthComponent : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private int _maxHealth;

        [SerializeField]
        private int _currentHealth;

        public delegate void HealthChanged();
        public event HealthChanged HealthChangedEvent;

        public void ChangeHealth(int amountToChangeBy)
        {            
            _currentHealth += amountToChangeBy;
            if (_currentHealth > _maxHealth)
            {
                _currentHealth = _maxHealth;
            }
            if (_currentHealth < 0)
            {
                _currentHealth = 0;
            }
            if (HealthChangedEvent != null)
            {
                HealthChangedEvent();
            }
        }
    }
```

You'd need to subscribe to the event in another class for it to be notified, e.g.

```
public class HealthSliderComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _healthSlider;

    private HealthComponent _healthComponent;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _healthComponent = GetComponent<HealthComponent>();
        _healthComponent.HealthChangedEvent += HandleHealthChanged;
    }

    private void HandleHealthChanged()
    {
        _healthSlider.value = _healthComponent.CurrentHealth;
    }
}
```